# What does this code want me to do?

Tags: java, character, java.util.scanner

Print the prompt "Character: " then use the Scanner object to read a string from the keyboard into a temporary variable that you must declare. Next extract the first character of the temporary string into myCharacter.

(Scanner is already initialized)

This is what I have so far but I don't understand what the question is asking.

```
char myCharacter;
char myCharacter1;
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Character: ");      

     myCharacter1 = kbd.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: you've done it. Congrats!

Comment: You're not reading the String into a temporary variable.

Comment: `String temporary = ...; char myCharacter = ...;`

Comment: Questions aren't codes

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it's doing what you were asked. The question is asking you to read in a string from user input and get the first character out of the string, which is this part of your code:

```
myCharacter1 = kbd.next().charAt(0);
```

As far as I can tell, it only cares about having the temporary string variable only so you can grab the first character out of it and store it in to your myCharacter1 variable. It might just be that it's trying to illustrate the idea that strings are an array of characters? I hope that helps!

-Frank

EDIT:
You had a comment that you weren't reading the string into a temporary string variable. That's an important step from your question. As far as I know, your code should work fine, but if this is a homework problem for a class your professor will likely deduct points for not reading into a String variable first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Scanner declaration and initialization.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // 1. Prompting 'Character: '
    System.out.print("Character: ");

    // 2. Temporary variable declaration and initialization.
    String tempVar = scanner.next();

    // 3. Extraction of the first character of the temporary variable into char variable
    char myCharacter = tempVar.charAt(0);
```